# Zip Web Application Folder

Tags: php, yii

I am using Zip Archive(php) to compress my web application, when I give it the directory c:/xampp/mywebapp, the function compress everything inside xampp folder and mywebapp folder, how can I put to compress only the directories inside mywebapp folder?

**FUNCTION**

```
function agregar_zip($dir, $zip){

            if (is_dir($dir)) {

                if ($da = opendir($dir)) {          

                    while (($archivo = readdir($da))!== false) {  

                        if (is_dir($dir . $archivo) && $archivo!="." && $archivo!=".."){

                        agregar_zip($dir.$archivo . "/", $zip);  



                        }elseif(is_file($dir.$archivo) && $archivo!="." && $archivo!=".."){

                        $zip->addFile($dir.$archivo, $dir.$archivo);                    
                        }            
                    }

                    closedir($da);
                }
            }      
        }
```

$dir = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/mywebapp/';

$zip = new ZipArchive();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify the target from windows but from host

```
$dir = 'mywebapp/';
```

Comment: I use Yii framework, I am in a controller, so this would be ../../mywebapp?

Comment: Yii:app()->basepath.'/../'

That is the solution :D